# Need to identify plants

Tags: identification, houseplants, plant-care, indoors

[image] I have 2  plants I got as gifts and don’t know how to care for them. Anyone have any idea what they are? One has thick. Curved leaves, if you can even call them that. It has a layer of short, fur like stuff that goes all over the leaves. Growing upward with a thick, tree like stem. It’s about the size of a hand. No idea what it is.
Second one I have has leaves similar to a succulent I have but the stem has a bark like layer and the stems are long, with a head of green thick, stiff leaves that look like a echeveria plant but I don’t think it is. I can’t add pictures because apparently they’re too large? I’ll try to add in the comments maybe after but if anyone knows something that partially matches these descriptions it would a a place to start for me.

Comment: Welcome! If you have two different plants, please post _two_ questions! If you have problems with photos, one of the most common causes is image size - try to stay under 2 MB.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty confident that the pictured plant is an Aeonium of some kind. The keys are

- The upright "trunk" and branching
- The flattened rosette of leaves at the end of each "stem"
- The way in which the leaves whorl about the center in each rosette
- The leaf shape

If this is an aeonium, then care is relatively easy, beginning with "DO NOT OVER WATER. Here's more information, from the site [World of Succulents](https://worldofsucculents.com/?genera=aeonium):

- Try to keep the plant at a temperature around 65-75°F (18-24°C), which mimics winter in their native habitat. If it gets too hot they may go dormant.
- Water only when the soil is completely dry down to a depth of at least one inch/2.5 cm.
- After watering, remove any water that's in the saucer after maybe 15 minutes or so.
- Feed only during their growing period with half-strength balanced fertilizer.

It's currently in a great pot - clay with a drainage hole. When it is time to transplant (after 2–3 years in the pot) use a regular potting mix because they do like some moisture in the soil.